# Add record from vf page to list on button click

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller-extension

I want to insert multiple records at a time, but whenever i try to insert a record and add to table all previous records get changed to the recent one.[image]

Here's the code
[image]

VF Page

```
<apex:page standardController="Position__c" extensions="PositionExtension">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pagemessages ></apex:pagemessages>
        <apex:pageBlock >            
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
                <apex:commandButton action="{!Add_Row}" value="Add Row" rerender="positions" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>

            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Position" columns="2">
                <apex:inputField value="{!Position__c.Name}" required="true"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Position__c.Status__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Position__c.Location__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Position__c.Type__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Position__c.Open_Date__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Position__c.Hire_By__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Position__c.Close_Date__c}"/>
                 <apex:pageBlockSectionItem /> <apex:pageBlockSectionItem /> 
                <apex:inputField value="{!Position__c.Functional_Area__c}"/>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem /> 
                <apex:inputField value="{!Position__c.Job_Level__c}"/>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem /> <apex:pageBlockSectionItem /> 
                <apex:inputField value="{!Position__c.Min_Pay__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Position__c.Max_Pay__c}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>   
        </apex:pageBlock>

        <apex:pageBlock >
           <apex:pageBlockTable id="positions" value="{!allrecords}" var="Position">
                <apex:column value="{!Position.Name}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!Position.Status__c}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!Position.Location__c}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!Position.Type__c}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!Position.Open_Date__c}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!Position.Hire_By__c}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!Position.Close_Date__c}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!Position.Job_Level__c}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!Position.Functional_Area__c}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!Position.Min_Pay__c}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!Position.Max_Pay__c}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>

            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
                <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>


        </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Can you post the VF code as well? Also are you re-rendering the list of records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason behind this is record is not getting instantiate again. So you need to instantiate record again with new. Update **Add_Row** method as below.

```
Position__c anotherRecord = new Position__c();
anotherRecord.Name = record.Name;
anotherRecord.Status__c = record.Status__c;
/*
  similarly copy other fileds as well for this new insatance
*/
allrecords.add(anotherRecord)
```

Comment: not working! after implementing this, it is redefining the allrecords list too.

Comment: UPDATE! As the record is set in constructor, it get executed only once, and when we reinitialize **record** , **record** returns empty for every _Add_Row()_ method call.

Comment: @SaumyaGaikwad  pls check above answer I have updated it. Because every time while adding records to list it suppose to be new.  I hope this will help you.

Comment: Great! wow.... I had almost lost hope on this! Thankyou

Comment: Is there any way to iterate over the fields available in the current context of controller to this scenario. I mean all the fields accessed in the VF will be available in the 'record = (Position__c)controller.getRecord();  ' context. Any way to iterate the fields too?